# Onclick function arguments

Tags: javascript, function, onclick, arguments, counter

I am trying to simulate a number counting up from 0 to 100 and I am having issues.
First I tried to use a for loop and send the iteration values to an `.innerHTML div`but it only showed the last number. So I searched online for a an animated javascript counter and I found this one: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/aJrj4/.

It works for my needs however I am not sure how to apply this so that it can be triggered by a button. This script is written with argument inputs when the function is defined, and then passes them at the end by running the function after wards. 
I cant figure out how do I input arguments for an `onclick` event?
This was my attempt but I keep getting errors, specifically with the `onclick` line.

```
var loadSim_btn = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];

loadSim_btn.onclick=function load_Sim(pCent, 25, 100, 2000);

function load_Sim (pCent, start, end, duration) {
  var range = end - start;
        // no timer shorter than 50ms (not really visible any way)
        var minTimer = 50;
        // calc step time to show all interediate values
        var stepTime = Math.abs(Math.floor(duration / range));
        // never go below minTimer
        stepTime = Math.max(stepTime, minTimer);
        // get current time and calculate desired end time
        var startTime = new Date().getTime();
        var endTime = startTime + duration;
        var timer;

        function run() {
            var now = new Date().getTime();
            var remaining = Math.max((endTime - now) / duration, 0);
            var value = Math.round(end - (remaining * range));
            obj.innerHTML = value;
            if (value == end) {
                clearInterval(timer);
            }
        }

        timer = setInterval(run, stepTime);
        run();
    }
```

**ANSWER:**
So the from what I can tell one issue was I forgot the obj definition line. In addition Joshua Davison answered my main question. 
"The onclick callback doesn't provide arguments, so we wrap the function call in an anonymous function (that takes no arguments)"
So my options for assigning the button in java script was:

> loadSim_btn.onclick=function() { load_Sim(pCent, 25, 100, 2000); }

and using an Event Listener:

> loadSim_btn.addEventListener("click", function() { load_Sim(pCent,
>   25, 100, 2000); }, true);

Comment: Please specify what errors you are having.

Comment: Are you looking to pass arguments or hard code the parameters?

Comment: The error is: js_code.js:19 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number
Line 19 is the button=onclick line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The onclick callback doesn't provide arguments, so we wrap the function call in an anonymous function (that takes no arguments)

```
loadSim_btn.onclick=function() { load_Sim(pCent, 25, 100, 2000); }
```

May I also recommend that you use event listeners rather than using onclick

```
loadSim_btn.addEventListener("click", function() { load_Sim(pCent, 25, 100, 2000); }, true);
```

Lastly, rather than using `getElementsByTagName(...)[0]`, it's preferable to use `getElementById("btnId")` if possible (only one element should have that ID) - and add `id="btnId"` to the button in the HTML

I hope this turns out OK (posting from my phone).

Comment: Is there any point to using .addEventListener instead of onclick?

Comment: Sorry for the (very!) delayed reply. onClick replaces any existing listeners, while addEventListener add's a listener.

I've had issues in the past where scripts have performed additional functions (click noise, animations, etc.) and always using onclick=... becomes a bad habit.

Answer (score 3):

Add a button and attach the same function as onclick handler. Like `<button type="button" onclick="animateValue('value', 0, 100, 2000)">Click</button>`. Please check this working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HectorBarbossa/fy7w2kfe/).

Comment: Thanks that worked. I kept trying to do it all in java script. In your method you assigned the functioned to the button directly inline of the html div.
Out of curiosity is this possible from within javascript?

Comment: Sure, you can do that by adding some code like document.getElementById("animateBtn").addEventListener("click", function(){ ... });

Answer (score 0):

You have to define `obj`.
Write something like:
`var obj = document.getElementById(pCent);`
At the top of `load_Sim`

Comment: And if "pCent" is the id of your output element, you have to write it as a string in line 2: `loadSim_btn.onclick=function load_Sim("pCent", 25, 100, 2000);`

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by ***@Hector Barbossa***; this can be accomplished by adding ***animateValue('value', 0, 100, 2000)*** to your html button element. Working example here [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aJrj4/97/).

**HTML:**

```
<div id="value">0</div>
<button type = "button" onclick = "animateValue('value', 0, 100, 20000)">Click</button>
```

**CSS:**

```
#value {
    font-size: 100px;
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
function animateValue(id, start, end, duration) {

    var obj = document.getElementById(id);
    var range = end - start;
    var minTimer = 50;
    var stepTime = Math.abs(Math.floor(duration / range));

    stepTime = Math.max(stepTime, minTimer);

    var startTime = new Date().getTime();
    var endTime = startTime + duration;
    var timer;

    function run() {
        var now = new Date().getTime();
        var remaining = Math.max((endTime - now) / duration, 0);
        var value = Math.round(end - (remaining * range));
        obj.innerHTML = value;
        if (value == end) {
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }

    timer = setInterval(run, stepTime);
    run();
}
```